# Express middleware separate instances

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a personal project for a photography web application.
Still very new to node.js and express.

The previous ASP.Net MVC app I built for this application used a SQL database to index photos and auto-generate the neccesary photo gallery markup.

[node-gallery](https://github.com/cianclarke/node-gallery)

seemed like a good candidate to remove the db dependency.

However I seem to be confused as to how Express middleware works.

```js
var nodeGallery = require('node-gallery');

//
//

app.use('/', new nodeGallery({
  staticFiles : 'public/photos/slideshow',
  urlRoot : 'photos/slideshow',
  render : false
}), function(req, res, next){
  rerurn res.render('index',{slideshow:req.data});
});

app.use('/portfolio', new nodeGallery({
  staticFiles : 'public/photos/portfolio',
  urlRoot : 'portfolio',
  render : false
}), function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.data);
  return res.render('portfolio',{portfolio:req.data});
});
```

I am wanting to use the node-gallery middleware with different properties for two pages (the front with a slideshow and the main gallery). However the last properties set are always used regardless of route.

Using express.Router and specifying a route which uses the middleware also appears to not work.

It seems like I am missing something basic here. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that what appears to be happening is actually happening?  You are correct in that `app.use`, `app.get`, `app.post`, etc., with a path will cause all the middleware after it to only run on that path.  Add a test middleware before your `nodeGallery` with a simple `console.log()` or something to prove which route is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var nodeGallery = require('node-gallery');
```

Think of this as creating a class/obj of node gallery.

Then in your first route you set its properties as:

```
 new nodeGallery({
  staticFiles : 'public/photos/slideshow',
  urlRoot : 'photos/slideshow',
  render : false
})
```

but in the second route you overwrite **nodeGallery** with a second set of properties:

```
 new nodeGallery({
  staticFiles : 'public/photos/portfolio',
  urlRoot : 'portfolio',
  render : false
})
```

The problem is you are using the same instance of nodeGallery, to define to sets of different properties.

**Solution:**

**1.** Create an object of multiple node-galleries i.e:

```
var nodeGallery = {
 slideShow: require('node-gallery'),
 mainGallery: require('node-gallery'),
}
```

and then access them as nodeGaller.slideShow({staticFiles....})

**2.** the better solution in my opinion would be to use the recommended way on the github page:

```
app.use('/gallery', require('node-gallery')({
  staticFiles : 'resources/photos',
  urlRoot : 'gallery', 
  title : 'Example Gallery'
}));
```

you're not setting node-gallery to any one variable, just initializing for that route.

Comment: solution 2 was what I used to start, following the examples on the project github page. Thats where I first noticed the issue.